# Is it possible manually sort objects in threejs?

Tags: sorting, three.js

Threejs has a parameter called renderOrder for objects, which allows threejs to sort them if the sortObjects = false for the renderer. Before sorting threejs divides the objects into two bins (a transparency and opaque bin). Each bin the objects are sorted. The opaque gets rendered first and there after the transparency.

If you set sortObjects to false then you are relying on the depthbuffer.

My question is there a way I can manually sort the objects? I would like to have all my objects in one bin since I am sorting from back to front and do not need two bins (which in my case messes things up). I do not use the depthbuffer.

Comment: Have you tried setting [`object.renderOrder`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.renderOrder)? That is the way to manually sort the objects.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy the renderOrder is actually the "order" I am talking about. I'll see if I can edit that word after this comment has been posted. The problem as described is that the renderOrder has two bins; one for transparent and one for opaque objects. I need more control.